# angular change variable after filling all inputs

Tags: angular, variables, input

I have several inputs in template

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" title="nanme">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="name" placeholder="surname" title="surname">
```

in ts file I have variable `testVar=false`;

I want `testVar=true` after both inputs will be filled (not empty). How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) in this way:

template:

```
<div [formGroup]="profileForm">
      <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" title="nanme">
      <input formControlName="surname" type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="name" placeholder="surname" title="surname">
     <p>
        {{profileForm.status}}
    </p>
</div>
```

component:

```
import {Validators, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
profileForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    surname: ['', Validators.required]
});
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
```

And instead of using `testVar`, you can use `profileForm.valid`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use local reference here #input1 and #input2 and make use of keydown.enter

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" title="nanme" #input1 (keydown.enter)="checkInputs(input1.value,input2.value)">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="name" placeholder="surname" title="surname" #input2 (keydown.enter)="checkInputs(input1.value,input2.value)">
```

and then in .ts file:

```
checkInputs(input1,input2) {
  if(input1.length && input2.length){
  this.testVar=true;
  }else{
  this.testVar=false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Template:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" title="nanme" [(ngModel)]="details.name" (ngModelChange)="checkTestValue()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" id="name" placeholder="surname" title="surname" [(ngModel)]="details.surname" (ngModelChange)="checkTestValue()">
```

TS:

```
 details: any = {};

  checkTestValue() {
    if (this.details.name && this.details.surname) {
      this.testVar = true;
    } else {
      this.testVar = false;
    }
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-87err7?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: User has mentioned in the question that template has several inputs, not just two. Also not necessarily all the input values can belong to one variable object, which is 'details' in your case.

Comment: @Hemendra In that case hecan use `Object.keys()`